Why is `~/.zlogout` not sourced when non-interactive ZSH shell runs `exit`?
My ~/.zlogout contains the following:
echo '~/.zlogout!'

Let's run the following script:
su user -ls /bin/zsh -c 'echo kaasbier; exit'

Nothing is echoed (besides the kaasbier). I am testing this in a vanilla archlinux VM.
Even if I do not run exit but logout, I still cannot trigger the logout script to be sourced. It does work, when exiting an interactive mode: su user -ls /bin/zsh.
Thus, why is ~/.zlogout (or /etc/zlogout) not sourced upon exiting an non-interactive login shell?

What is a "non-interactive login shell"? Isn't that an oxymoron? How exactly are you invoking zsh? I'm guessing your zlogout wasn't getting sourced because you weren't actually in a login shell. Zsh's docs are a bit sparse about login vs non-login shells compared to bash's docs on the topic.

@Spiff A non-interactive login shell is rare, but if you run a command as shown in my post, or like bash -lc 'echo $-' it is a login, but non-interactive.
I checked if I was in a login shell by running echo $-, which printed an i, using zsh.

Thanks for your time so far @Spiff !
I believe we might have a miscommunication. I do not use sudo.
Following your advise, I adopted the command in my original post to be this: su user -ls /bin/zsh -c 'setopt'. This does print 'login'. Thus, I believe to correctly invoke my shells as login. This means that in the example in my post, the logoout script should have been sourced on exit - as far as I understand things.

Oops my bad. You wrote su and my brain read sudo.

I bet that it is not a login shell. Do a echo $- to find out. If the string contains a l (lower case L), you have a login shell.

I just tested with the following command: su user -ls /bin/zsh -c 'echo $-'. It prints 569xl` @user1934428, thus it's a login shell.

There is something odd in your findings, which may be worth investigating: Your su -l starts as login shell the shell defined by user (this could be i.e. bash or zsh). This login shell then executes the zsh command, and since you don't specify a -l, this zsh should be a non-interactive non-login shell. Hence, if your default shell specified in /etc/passwd were bash, this would explain why .logout is not run. However, I don't understand why you see a login shell in the echo command. It shouldn't be one.

I just found a sentence in the man-page which could be useful: _ However, if the shell terminates due to exec'ing  another process, the logout files are not read._ While this does not tell us why your zsh -c creates a login shell, it explains that .zlogout can not be executed .

In addition, note that sourcing .zlogout can be suppressed dynamically, if the RCS option is unset (say, in your .zprofile). See the section Initialisation in the zsh man page.

@user1934428 this sentence confuses me: "Your su -l starts as login shell the shell defined by user (this could be i.e. bash or zsh). This login shell then executes the zsh command, and since you don't specify a -l, this zsh should be a non-interactive non-login shell." You mention that -l is not specified, whilst your example - and my examples - include -l. My .zprofile is empty, and as far as I know I do not let zsh exec some other shell or process.

@Silas: Your example provides -l for su, but not for zsh.
